# Azure Functions 2.0 Not Loading Referenced Libraries

Tags: azure-functions

I've created a new Azure Function in VS 2017.

Ran it, debugged it.

Then referenced a library of shared code and modified the code to call into the library.

Re-ran the function, upon calling the function it dies loading one of the dependent DLLs.

This seems to be publishing as a precompiled function and the inner bin that is referenced in the function.json as the home for the "scriptFile" has the DLLs including the one that is failing to load.

`[1/5/2018 4:04:18 AM] ScriptHost initialization failed
[1/5/2018 4:04:18 AM] System.Private.CoreLib: Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Abstractions, Version=2.0.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60'. Could not find or load a specific file. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131621). System.Private.CoreLib: Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Abstractions, Version=2.0.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60'.`

Is there a trick to getting the function to load these DLLs?

Comment: This could be a bug. Can you please open a bug in [azure-webjobs-sdk-script](https://github.com/Azure/azure-webjobs-sdk-script/) repo with repro steps?

Comment: Can you share the exact exception you're seeing when loading the dependency?

Comment: @FabioCavalcante I have added the exact exception. I have successfully created a V1 function project referencing the same shared library.

Comment: Having the exact same issue