# How to create VSTS CI-CD for Azure Functions (with shared javascript files) using Visual Studio Code?

Tags: javascript, git, azure-devops, mongoose-schema, azure-functions-core-tools

I'm trying to use Visual Studio code to create a Azure Function micro-service (javascript and Functions v2) that I push to my VSTS account, that then triggers a CI-CD to Azure functions.

**How do I configure the Azure Functions CI-CD process to bring across all of the files in my VSTS git repo?**

Has anyone gotten this working? Is there a better way to connect the Azure Function to a CosmosDb while having shared javascript model files (I've seen numerous examples in C# on microsoft, but not for Javascript)?

Preferred dev env: VS Code -> VSTS Git CI-CD -> Azure Function -> Azure CosmosDb

What I'm trying to achieve:

- Step 1: I did a great tutorial that gets an Angular page linking to a Azure Http Trigger Function (https://dzone.com/articles/create-a-serverless-angular-app-with-azure-functio)
- Step 2: I like Visual Studio Code and want to be able to use it to develop a more sophistacated micro-service (https://www.michaelcrump.net/azure-tips-and-tricks50/)
- Step 3: I managed to do the advised "Upload" to Azure and the functions arived and worked ... nice one old-mate! (https://www.michaelcrump.net/azure-tips-and-tricks52/)
- Step 4: I pushed my 2 Functions (one from first tutorial and the other just the standard Hello-world created in VS Code) to VSTS, and created a Azure side CI-CD pull.  This works, but VSTS has no Build or Deploy scripts I can see or edit. [https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-continuous-deployment]
- Step 5: I want to create a RESTful Azure Function microservice to use mongoose and connect to Azure CosmosDb. This is the best I can find that suggests how using Azure CLI. (http://thecodebarbarian.com/getting-started-with-azure-functions-and-mongodb.html)
- Step 6: I want to have a shared model files as the microservice becomes more sophisticated.  ([How to share code in JavaScript Azure Functions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44612507/how-to-share-code-in-javascript-azure-functions))

**Problem** ... The CI-CD I setup in Azure Function isn't bringing my shared sub-directory over and therefore the entire Function breaks.  The CI-CD in VSTS doesn't include any details of the CI-CD Build and Release steps in the VSTS web UI (no processes are setup).

How do you create a shared subdirectory between functions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hmmm, seems that Beta really means Beta.  I updated the VS Code plugin using the command line and seems to have resolved the issue.  Though it did break the CI-CD that was setup.  Doing a VS Code to Azure release pushed everything up.  I'm yet to reconfig the TSVS CI-CD.

[Azure Functions 2.0 Not Loading Referenced Libraries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48039880/azure-functions-2-0-not-loading-referenced-libraries)